# How to get the exact matched record in rails 3?

Tags: sql, ruby, rails-activerecord

Items in the database:

```
 => [#<Item id: 1, item_collection: [:LAPTOP, :COMPUTER, :MOUSE, :SPEAKER]>, 
     #<Item id: 2, item_collection: [:LAPTOPANDKEYBOARD, :DISK, :SCREEN]>]
```

Below query will give me both the records (which include LAPTOP and LAPTOPANDKEYBOARD).

```
Item.where("item_collection like ?", "%LAPTOP%")

 => [#<Item id: 1, item_collection: [:LAPTOP, :COMPUTER, :MOUSE, :SPEAKER]>, 
     #<Item id: 2, item_collection: [:LAPTOPANDKEYBOARD, :DISK, :SCREEN]>]
```

But I only want the record which has LAPTOP only.

```
#<Item id: 1, item_collection: [:LAPTOP, :COMPUTER, :MOUSE, :SPEAKER]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialized arrays add a `\n` at the end of each item, so you can try this:

```
Item.where("item_collection LIKE ?", "%LAPTOP\n%")
```

Another option would be to fetch all the data and then filter it with `select`, like this:

```
Item.all.select { |item| item.item_collection.include?(:LAPTOP) }
```

Comment: That will return me empty array [].

Comment: @Kavincat Sorry, i missed that you are using a serialized field; check updated answer.

Comment: @Kavincat After some testing i think i figured out how to do it with sql; check updated answer (again).

Comment: @Thanks but the query with `include?` (which you have posted before) was 2x faster than this.

Comment: @Kavincat Oh i'll add the two options then :)